# Downloading Secure File in Azure DevOps is returning "unable to verify the first certificate error"

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to add the a "DownloadSecureFile@1" task in YAML script in Azure DevOps Server that will run on a self-hosted agent in LINUX server.

**This is the task added:**

```
task: DownloadSecureFile@1
name: envconfig
displayName: 'Copy env config file'
inputs:
secureFile: 'env.local'
```

**And this is the error I got:**

```
##[section]Starting: Copy env config file
Task : Download secure file
Description : Download a secure file to a temporary location on the agent machine
Version : 1.151.2
Author : Microsoft Corporation
Help : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file
##[error]Error: unable to verify the first certificate
##[section]Finishing: Copy env config file
```

I have tried to add a new task in YAML script and also set some permissions to have administrator access to the secure file, but the issue is still occurring:

> unable to verify the first certificate

The actual server for Azure DevOps and LINUX agent has HTTPS enabled.

How can I resolve this issue?